# Google Maps API ignore traffic rules

Tags: google-maps

I'm programming a software based on google maps api for emergency vehicles. Is it possible to make the directions api allow breaking traffic rules (like turning left where it's not allowed)? 
Thank you

Comment: Can you at least provide a link to your specific *directions API*? Have you read through its documentation? Usually such stuff is written somewhere there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is still possible with the latest version of Maps API. It is still a feature request.

Also, I don't see if a workaround exists.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is even worse thing that might disallow using of Google Maps API in applications for emergency vehicles.

Have a look at paragraph 10.2 (g) of Terms of Service. It reads:

> **General Google API Restrictions.** The following restrictions apply generally to all Google Services, including the Google application programming interfaces at https://developers.google.com/products/ (or such other URL as Google may provide) (the “Google API(s)”). **You will not:**
>
> g. Use the Google APIs for any activities where the use or failure of the Google APIs could lead to death, personal injury, or environmental damage (such as the operation of nuclear facilities, air traffic control, or life support systems).

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?#section_10_2